# How should I remove all the repeated words and letters of a String?

Tags: string, algorithm, suffix-tree

I am trying to remove every character repeated over 2 times from an extremely long string. So, for example, the word `Terrrrrrific` becomes `Terrific`.

Now my question is, how do I filter out repeats that include more than a single character the same way, i.e. if I have `Words words words words words` I want to filter it down to `words words`, however, it might be something less sensible, such as `abcdabcdabcdabcdabcd` which should become `abcdabcd`.

I do suspect that I should use a suffix tree, but I'm not sure how to go at the algorithm exactly.

Comment: What you're looking for are also known as "tandem repeats" (due to a related task involving DNA sequences).  When you allow more than one character, you have to define carefully what you mean by a repeat: e.g. `words words words words words` also contains 3 (overlapping) repeats of the string `words words words`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, Is this efficient algorithm for you but you can do this:

1. Choose length for finding repeats
2. Then for every start point from 0 to length-1 go through string
3. Maintain stack (you use disjoint substrings and push on stack if top two from stack is different from them)